# How to place a enumerate environment within an if statement?

Tags: lists, enumerate, conditionals

Why does the following minimal working example produces an error unless the enumerate environment is removed? Is there a simple workaround?

```
\documentclass[10pt,presentation]{beamer}

\newif\ifexercise
\exercisetrue
%\exercisefalse

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}
\begin{frame}{Some Slide}
\ifexercise
    What is the answer to everything?
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 42
        \item 43
    \end{enumerate}
\else
\fi
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm tempted to just answer **42** but someone would be bound to downvote.

Comment: `beamer` does lots of weird stuff, you can use `\begin{frame}[fragile]{Some Slide}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the [`etoolbox` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox?lang=en), you can replace your `\if` with a `bool`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,presentation]{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbool{exercise}
\booltrue{exercise}
\boolfalse{exercise}

\begin{document}

\section{Some Section}
\begin{frame}{Some Slide}
\ifbool{exercise}{%
    What is the answer to everything?
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item 42
        \item 43
    \end{enumerate}%
}{}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```